# Best deterministic algorithm makes twice the mistakes the best expert makes

Tags: convex-optimization, game-theory

I am reading the proof of Theorem 1.1. of [Elad Hazan, Introduction to Online Convex Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05207). It is not making sense to me. Given any deterministic algorithm the adversary can always choose the opposite action at each step. Thus no deterministic algorithm can guarantee even one single correct action. There must be some condition that is not explicitly spelled out in the setting, or I have missed something obvious. Can someone elucidate?

Comment: But you want to relate this to the number of mistakes *the best expert makes.* If your algorithm makes 0 good predictions (it's bad!), but every expert also is always wrong (everyone is bad!), then that's fine -- how would you do better than zero anyway? Here, the proof is saying the algorithm does badly (0 good predictions!) **while the best expert does quite well** (half their predictions are good)

Comment: It would help to create better content for Math.SE if you phrased your Question more carefully.  The third sentence in the body of your Question is ungrammatical.

Comment: @ClementC.: There are many things that are unclear to me. 1) How is the algorithm chosen related to the experts? 2) Why does he assume there are only 2 experts? Is he saying 2 is the "worst" case? These are so vague.

Comment: @Hans The algorithm is arbitrary. But as long as you allow $n \geq 2$ experts in your setting, you can have two doing this (one always saying $A$, one only saying $B$) and the adversary choosing to say the opposite of what your algo says. Then the best expert (among $n$) does at least as well as the best among those two, and among those two there is always one which is correct at least half the time. So you algo makes 0 good predictions, while there is at least one expert getting at least half of the predictions correct.

Comment: Remember this is a lower bound "in the worst case" so you get to design both the adversary and the experts: what you don't get to choose is the algorithm's behavior.

Comment: @ClementC.: It is still unclear. 1) With regard to experts, are you saying you can put in as many "experts" as you like? Then put in as many to cover the set of all paths, say $N^T$ where $n$ is the number of possible actions for each step. That will guarantee the best expert making $0$ mistakes. 2) The last sentence states "Therefore, there is no algorithm that can always guarantee less than 2L mistakes." While you say the algorithm is independent of the experts, the word "therefore" presumably indicates the last sentence derives from the preceding statements regarding experts.

Comment: @Hans As long as you are in a setting where you have $n\geq 2$ experts, you can "embed" this hard case where 2 of the experts behave as stated in the proof. (The number of experts is fixed; the proof does not go through if you are in a setting with only one expert, but then that's not a setting where this whole type of algorithms makes sense). The therefore says that, for every fixed deterministic algorithm supposed to work in a setting with at least 2 experts, there exist an adversary and a choice of experts which wil force that algo to make at least twice as many errors as the best expert.